Error: No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=electron abi=114 uv=1 libc=glibc node=18.14.0 electron=24.8.5 webpack=true
I am using electron to write a 'serialport' program, using npm to run dev environment is normal to use and tune, but after build, enter the page with the following error
Error: No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=electron abi=114 uv=1 libc=glibc node=18.14.0 electron=24.8.5 webpack=true
    loaded from: D:\item\gitlab\cmmop_host_v2\host-window\factory-program-ui\build\win-unpacked\resources\app\dist

What am I doing wrong?
Platform：windows11
version:
 node=18.14.0 
 electron=24.8.5 
 vue=2.7.14
 serialport=12


